# How can I get the id of an element and then choose the element later with id?

Tags: jquery

Am I correct in saying that the following will give me the id of an element?

```
$('#detailData').on('click', '.select-topic', function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

If that's correct then is it possible for me to perform a delayedclick on that element
with the code below. What I am not sure of is how do I code the jQuery selector? How can I enter in the id and the # mark together?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery('???').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#' + id)`?

Comment: Seems like it should work, though I'd suggest `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`, just because it's cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the id will work but why not just cache the jQuery selector in the first place.
That will also then work in cases where the element may not have an id specified.

Another benefit of caching the value to begin with is that you do not have to constantly re-create the jQuery object when you want to use it, saving on performance too.

```
var $selectTopic;

$('#detailData').on('click', '.select-topic', function (event) {
    $selectTopic = $(this);
})
```

The later use the jQuery object directly.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $selectTopic.trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

If for some reason you need the selector string again to maybe query for nested elements you can use:

```
$($selectTopic.selector + ' #anotherElementInside');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#detailData').on('click', '.select-topic', function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Now you got the id, and select that element with '#'

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + id).trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```